# How can a Thread that is asleep receive events?

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, runnable

My code:

```
public class EventHandler implements Runnable, SomeEventListener {
    private static final EventHandler INSTANCE = new EventHandler();
    private static final Thread THREAD = new Thread(INSTANCE);
    private static volatile boolean isRunning = false;

    private EventHandler () {}

    private static EventHandler getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void start() {
        isRunning = true;
        THREAD.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    //Listener method that was overriden
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        //...do stuff
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do nothing, let the listener do its job
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                logger.info("Sleeping...");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                logger.info("Done sleeping...");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    } 
}
```

}
Basically the `run()` method does nothing - just sleeps every 5 seconds, wakes up, sleeps again. What I don't understand is when it's asleep, this `EventHandler` class still gets events. How does this happen? Shouldn't the class stop receiving events since the thread is asleep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread and the class are two different things. EventHandler is an object that has a dedicated thread executing its run method. At the same time it has its onEvent method which is available to get called by other threads.

Log the thread ID in the onEvent method and in the run method to confirm the sleeping thread is not involved in receiving events.

Classes don't own threads. Your THREAD is spinning doing its sleeping, logging, and flag-checking, while other threads in your program call onEvent. (Also the OS-level thread is a separate thing from the object whose reference you saved as THREAD.)

You could use a thread pool and that would keep your application alive until you shut it down. It would be better to submit Runnables to a thread pool than to give each Runnable its own dedicated thread.

Comment: So are you saying that the EventHandler class has two Threads? One dedicated for EventHandler itself and one just for the run method?

Comment: @Miguel: it's called by other threads. the same way you call stop from another thread.

Comment: @MiguelPortugal, Classes don't have threads.  A class is a structure that defines the layout of data, and defines the methods that operate on the data.  "Thread" is the name of the thing in Java that _executes_ methods.  Some thread in your program executes the EventHandler's `start()` method:  That makes a _new_ thread that will execute the run() method.  Meanwhile, some _other_ thread (maybe the same as the one that called start(), maybe not.  Can't tell without seeing more of your code) is free to call onEvent().

Answer (score 2):

That thread seems really useless. I don't know how you think Listeners work, but basically they are just references that some thread you probably never saw will use to call certain methods if they see something happen.

A listener does not just "catch" any events thrown into the room.

Like I said: This thread seems useless because it doesn't do anything. At all. The Events are called from a different thread. You don't need this one for it.

Comment: I know that the Thread seems useless. I only put it there to prevent my standalone Java application from exiting once the main() finishes. Is there anyway I can stop my application from exiting besides this crappy run implementation?

Comment: Aren't you registering your listener somewhere? What kind of events are you trying to catch anyway? Since you don't seem to use a graphical user interface (which would keep the application alive with it's own thread), I'm really starting to wonder. Operating System Events? If so, I won't have enough knowledge to help you with that ^^

Comment: I'm handling events that pushed from a PBX system. Basically phone events. Someone calls, someone talks, etc... All these events are being handled by my app. Yes I don't have a GUI and yes it isn't a web-app. It's just a plain standalone Java app :)

Comment: Sry if I seem a little confused, it's just that this is kind of like if Swing would have it's main thread in some action listener class for a button. Alright, yes, you will have to keep that thing alive. I agree with that ^^ Still... at the very least I think I'd split the EventHandler from the Thread. It just seems misplaced.

Comment: @MiguelPortugal If the problem is that main() finishes, then why do you let main() finish?  Alternately, if the program exits when main() finishes, it is because the main thread is the only _non-daemon_ thread.  If the intent is for the program to keep running after main() finishes, then why are all of its other threads daemons?

Comment: @jameslarge Hi James. I'm not really sure how to answer your question as I have limited knowledge about daemon and non-daemon threads.

Comment: @Miguel: daemon-thread just means the thread's existence doesn't keep the jvm alive the way a normal thread does. once all non-daemon threads terminate the jvm terminates, killing all the daemon threads with no notice and no chance to clean up. really think you should probably revisit your design and consider using a threadpool.